# Serial port communication on android device with attached printer

Tags: java, android, printing, serial-port

I have an Android device which has a small printer attached to it directly.  The printer uses what seems to be a trimmed down version of ESC/POS language and communication with the printer is done by opening a serial port connection.

I am able to print single lines of text or have it print a barcode, but I can not manage to print multiple lines one after another.  There is no exception thrown, the printer simply prints one of the lines sent and then stops, subsequent attempts have the same result.

After trying many different combinations and sequences of commands, I have had no luck getting this to work.  I have some experience in Java but am not an expert at all.

Is there anything obviously wrong with the code below?

```
public void startPrint(String barcode){

        sp = new fingerprint_native();
    sp.OpenSerialPort("/dev/eser1")             

        byte[] space_cmd = new byte[3];
        space_cmd[0] = 27;
        space_cmd[1] = 74;
        space_cmd[2] = 50;

        String compName = "Test Company";
        String compAdd1 = "123 Main St.";
        String compAdd2 = "Cityname, ON A4A 4A4";
        String ticketNum = "1234567";
        byte[] cn = compName.getBytes();
        byte[] ca1 = compAdd1.getBytes();
        byte[] ca2 = compAdd2.getBytes();
        byte[] tn = ticketNum.getBytes();

        byte[] t = {0x0a, 0x0d};


        try {
            sp.WriteSerialPort(yn);
            sp.WriteSerialPort(t);
            sp.WriteSerialPort(ya1);
            sp.WriteSerialPort(ya2);
            sp.WriteSerialPort(tn);
            sp.WriteSerialPort(space_cmd);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "write text failed");
        }

    byte[] cmd12 = {0x1d, 0x6b, 68, 7};
    byte[] cmd11 = barcode.getBytes();

    byte[] bc = new byte[cmd12.length+cmd11.length];
    System.arraycopy(cmd12, 0, bc, 0, cmd12.length);
    System.arraycopy(cmd11, 0, bc, cmd12.length, cmd11.length);

        try {
            sp.WriteSerialPort(bc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "write barcode failed");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a carriage return/new line command that you need to send to tell it to get ready to print the next line?

Comment: Is this issue is resolved?? I know about POS printers, that it will print only when the data sent to be printed has a length of certain characters (~40 characters not exactly sure). So try sending data in multiple of 40 characters